# C++ syntax who appealed a code block - simplify the work

Tags: c++, syntax

It's possible to make my own "syntax" for a code block?
For, example I want to appeal this block of code 3 times in my program.

I have an file:

```
ofstream myFile("file.txt")
```

and I want to use an syntax, like "write" (or short, just "w") instead of

```
myFile<<i;
```

It's possible?

Comment: You need to learn how to use [functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/). If you really want to have your syntax the way you wrote it, maybe a macro could be used... But it's best if you use a function.

Comment: What does 'appeal a code block' mean?

Answer (score 0):

You would create a function:

```
void good_bad(int i)
{
    if(i%2) cout<<"Good for us";
    else cout<<"Bad for us";
}
```

And call it like this:

```
good_bad();
```

Comment: I look for an alternative method. This is just an example. 
I have an file: ofstream myFile("file.txt")
and I want to use an syntax, like write(or short, just w) for myFile<<i;

Comment: @GameZoneRO Please stick to C++ conventions and don't invent your own dialect. `<<` is the standard way for writing things to a file, and it's for a good reason. You can chain these together, like `f << y << z` which is way less mess than `f.write(y).write(z)`. Get used to the notation and you'll be fine.

Comment: @GameZoneRO You look for an alternative method why?